# DoocuSign New UI Branding

Tags: c#, email, docusignapi, branding

In the new DocuSign UI, we have our corporate logo. And that comes up correctly.
But below that is a huge image that says,
 has sent you a document to review and sign. 
And a button to Review the document.
It looks ugly. How do I make it smaller and prettier? Is it in email resources? I can't figure it out. Please help.
I am using SOAP API in C#. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Re-Read your question... pretend you had never seen your UI before.. infact pretend you don't even know what docusign is... then ask if this question makes any sense or if perhaps... just perhaps... more information might be needed. Please spend a little time and effort making sure your question is of a certain standard!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is controlled through the Email Resources file.  You can find the information about the new version of it in this [DocuSign Email Resource File Information Guide](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-email-resource-file(v1.1).pdf).  You do end up having to manipulate the HTML directly which is somewhat risky to keep retrofitted as DocuSign releases updates.